# What does the phrase "on a conveyance" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a definition of the word "car" (from TFD)
3. A boxlike enclosure for people or cargo **on a conveyance**: an elevator car.

What does "**on a conveyance**" mean?

TFD Definitions for the word "conveyance"

1. The act of conveying.
2. A means of conveying, especially a vehicle for transportation.

Could the example sentence mean "A boxlike enclosure for cargo o people **on a means of transportation like a rope in the case of an elevator**?

...or perhaps

"A boxlike enclosure for cargo o people **that are being conveyed**?

Answer (score 2):

A conveyance is [a means of transport (2)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conveyance). Some dictionaries say it's either [old-fashioned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conveyance) or [formal](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conveyance).

A lift is a conveyance. It transports people or freight.

A system of traction cables is also a conveyance. It transports things attached to it: a lift car, a cable car.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means **on a vehicle**. One of the meanings of **car** is 'the compartment in which the passengers sit'.

Comment: I think Andrew gave the right answer to this. I'm not sure if you read the question carefully Kate. So basically "an elevator on a rope" can mean the same as "elevator on a conveyance" right?

Comment: @StaticBounce No one would ever call a rope "a conveyance", though.  It doesn't really make sense to say the elevator is *on* a conveyance, because the elevator is the conveyance.  I think you are worrying too much about the details of the definition.  It is only saying that a car is a boxlike enclosure, and an elevator car is one kind of this thing.

Comment: @StaticBounce - I certainly read the question carefully. The car is the part of the conveyance which contains the passengers. The example given is _an elevator car_, where the 'conveyance' is the whole system, not just the cable.